# Error when checking if popup window is open

Tags: android, popupwindow

My app runs continuously  and because of this I get a lot of popup windows open at the same time. I have tried to put following code:

```
 if (pwindo.isShowing())
            {
                pwindo.dismiss();
            }
```

in places of my code marked by **********************************:

```
public class travel extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PopupWindow pwindo;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_layout2);
 mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }



 private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
 {
        public void run() 
        {
            for (int i=begin;i<=end;i++)
            {
                if ((gps > Float.parseFloat(words[2+i*6])-0.11)&& (counter==i)&&(gps < Float.parseFloat(words[2+i*6])))
                {
                    if ((words[3+i*6]!= null && !words[3+i*6].isEmpty())||(number==end)||(count>0)) {
                        initiatePopupWindow();
                    }
                }
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
            if (gps > latEnd)
            {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }
       }
    };





//****************************************************
    private void initiatePopupWindow() 
    {
//****************************************************
        try 
        {
//****************************************************
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_popup,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 700, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, true);
//****************************************************
            pwindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
        //****************************************************
            pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
```

but it didn't work in any case. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? (inOncreate function I am calling runnable function, which runs every couple seconds and if some conditions are fulfilled initiatePopupWindow() function is called in order to open popup window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before calling initiatePopupWindow() check if `pwindo` is already there.

It is likely that you are getting popups layering ontop of themselves and the `pwindo` variable is only storing the address of the most recent one.

Comment: I have tried to do it before calling initiatePopupWindow(), but then I am getting this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.PopupWindow.isShowing()' on a null object reference

Comment: I think it's  because pwindo wasn't actually initialised,

Comment: Then just check to see `if (pwindo != null && pwindo.isShowing() == false) {// call to pop it up}` Java will break processing of the conditional after first null check and not call the rest of the conditional, so no worry about null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can set flag for it.
Like;

```
if(flag)
{
initiatePopupWindow();

flag==false;
}
```